# Getting Full HTML Source code in when using WP REST API

Tags: rest, wordpress

Installed WP REST API v2Beta13 on Wordpress version 4.4.2 from [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/), and also gone through it's documentation.

When trying to use the api via POSTMAN and hitting URL: 
`http://www.example.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` as a `GET` request, whole HTML code of home-page (`http://www.example.com/blog/`) is returned as response.
In fact any URL is giving the html code of home page.

Expect output should be json formatted data as mentioned in it's documentation.

Permalinks setting in wordpress admin-panel is set to `http://example.com/blog/sample-post/`

Comment: It sounds like, you probably need to use authentication first?

Comment: for even extracting posts too ?
they are public

Comment: it says that in the authentication, part worth a try, add `_wpnonce` on your request as a parameter alternatively use the curl method on your CMD to confirm. `curl ....wp-json/wp/v2/posts/123`

Comment: also, have a look at this article (in particular the answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470998/cant-authenticate-with-basic-authentication-using-wp-rest-api-2-0-plugin?rq=1 it may be your htaccess according to his/her problem (might be totally unrelated but worth a check)

Comment: @Val Can you give a complete example for the curl command that you mentioned, using  `_wpnonce` as a parameter.

Comment: if you post your domain name, I can give it a try, then you can delete the comment

Comment: @val basic auth worked fine, but can we just extract posts without auth ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109696/discussion-between-val-and-lazy-rabbit).