# Only "get" is allowed by REST-API in WordPress

Tags: json, wordpress, api, http-post, http-get

In my WordPress side, I installed REST-API plugin and successfully getting posts by:

```
mywp.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

However, only "get" is allowed, it return 401 if I do any other things like "post". I am using chrome app "Postman" and Basic Auth.

What I get:

```
  "code": "rest_cannot_create",
  "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create new posts.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
```

Here is the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →
Access-Control-Expose-Headers →X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Allow →GET
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Length →111
Content-Type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

I found a question asked the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453726/) but the answer didn't work for me.

I am new in rest-api and not sure what I should do.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself. As I was so careless to miss the part "Install [Basic Auth plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) in WP" in doc.
After I install and enable it, I am able to "post" and "delete" posts right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a WordPress instance deployed from Bitnami and are getting errors like:

- "`woocommerce_rest_cannot_create`" ("`Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.`")
- "`rest_cannot_create`" (`"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user."`)
- "`rest_cannot_create_user`" ("`Sorry, you are not allowed to create new users`")

Here is what resolved the issue for me:

- Install [Basic Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth), you can install it by cloning the repo into `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins` or you can also download the repo as a zip and install from a file from the plugins page in WP Admin.
- Edit the `.htaccess` file available in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`
- Add a new line under `RewriteEngine On` and insert `RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` save and exit
- Edit `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf` add a new line after `RewriteEngine On`
- In the new line insert: `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` save and exit
- Restart Apache: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`
- (OPTIONAL) Install [Application Passwords By George Stephanis](https://github.com/georgestephanis/application-passwords)

For more details check:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/setting-up-api-access-to-wordpress-on-aws-ec2-instance/60589/7

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when working on WP APIs and the I was solved the issue by adding three lines in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

You can follow the link for more details.

[More details to add lines in .htaccess](https://github.com/imranhsayed/react-with-wordpress/)